# "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" in html form

Tags: php, html, forms, textbox

I created a HTML form with textbox linked to a dropdown list. When I input the zip code in the textbox, the dropdown list on the right should be populated with the corresponding countries.

Instead, I become the error:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> /var/www/html/index.php on line 58, referer: http://127.0.0.1/html/

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Listes li&eacute;es en JQuery</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../images/site/favicon.ico" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        
        <!-- Linked Lists -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.chained.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Updating departements -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
            $("#departement").chained("#region");
            });
        </script>
        
        <!-- Updating communes -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
            $("#commune").chained("#codepostal");
            });
        </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
        // Connecting to database
        $bddname = 'database';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'user';
        $password = 'pass';
        $db = mysqli_connect ($hostname, $username, $password, $bddname);
        $db -> set_charset("utf8");
?>

<form method="post">
    <select name="region" id="region">
        <option value="">Sélectionner une région</option>
        <?php
            // Call up regions and display them in dropdown list
            $req = "SELECT RegionId, NomRegion FROM regions ORDER BY NomRegion";        
            $rep = mysqli_query($db, $req);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rep)) {
                echo "<option value=".$row['RegionId'].">".$row['NomRegion']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select name="departement" id="departement">
        <option value="">Sélectionner un département</option>
        <?php
            // Call up departments and display them in dropdown list
            $req = "SELECT DepartementId, RegionId, NomDepartement FROM departements ORDER BY NomDepartement";
            $rep = mysqli_query($db, $req);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rep)) {
                echo "<option value=".$row['DepartementId']." class=".$row['RegionId'].">".$row['NomDepartement']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>

     <!-- Zip Code Textbox -->  
     <input type="text" name="codepostal" id="codepostal" value="<?php $row['CodePostal']; ?>">
            
     <select name="commune" id="commune">
        <option value="">Sélectionner une commune</option>
        <?php
            // Call up countries and display them in dropdown list
            $req = "SELECT NomCommune FROM communes;
                            LEFT JOIN communeCP;
                            ON communeCP.CommuneId = communes.CommuneId;
                            LEFT JOIN codesPostaux;
                            ON codesPostaux.CodePostalId = communeCP.CodePostalId;
                            WHERE codesPostaux.CodePostal = ".$row["CodePostal"]." ORDER BY NomCommune";
            $rep = mysqli_query($db, $req);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rep)) {
                echo "<option value=".$row['communeId']." class=".$row['CodePostal'].">".$row['NomCommune']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input type="text" name="codepostal" id="codepostal" value="<?php $row['CodePostal']; ?>">` <- here `$row` is null, as you're no longer within the query result loop.

Comment: Thank you, but how could I do this ?

Comment: What should the "codepostal" (zipcode) input's default value be? There's one per department, and you have only one input for it. You probably don't want to have any default value there.

Comment: No, I don't want to have a default value for zipcode. The user enters a zipcode, then the field to the right should automatically populate with the corresponding countries.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery change eventListener.

```
$('#codepostal').on('change', fnuction(evt){
   $('#commune').html(mockCommuneOptions());
})

//return mock options
function mockCommuneOptions(){
  const options = ['a','b','c']
  let optiionsStr = '';
  options.forEach(option => {
    optiionsStr += `<option value='${option}'>${option}</option`;
  });

return optiionsStr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arab, but how could I display the corresponding country list from sql query instead of abc ?

Comment: I think you should learn some basic staff first. please have go through the article, I hope it would help you on this issue https://makitweb.com/how-to-handle-ajax-request-on-the-same-page-php/

Comment: Yes, I'm a newbie. I took a look on the article. But it doesn't help me, I don't know how to use this to send the text field value to my sql request.

Answer (score 0):

So, tested it with AJAX. Know, my script is working without any errors in my apache2 log. But, It displays [] between the input box and the right handed listbox and nothing happens when I enter a zip code.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Listes li&eacute;es en JQuery</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../images/site/favicon.ico" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
     
    <!-- Linked Lists -->        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.chained.js"></script>
      
    <!-- Updating departements -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#departement").chained("#region");
        });
    </script>
      
</head>
 
    <body>
    <?php
        // Connecting to database
        $bddname = 'database';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'user';
        $password = 'pass';
        $db = mysqli_connect ($hostname, $username, $password, $bddname);
        $db -> set_charset("utf8");
    ?>
            
    <form method="post">
        <select name="region" id="region">
            <option value="">Sélectionner une région</option>
                <?php
                    // Call up regions and display them in dropdown list
                    $req = "SELECT RegionId, NomRegion FROM regions ORDER BY NomRegion";        
                    $rep = mysqli_query($db, $req);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rep)) {
                        echo "<option value=".$row['RegionId'].">".$row['NomRegion']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            
            <select name="departement" id="departement">
                <option value="">Sélectionner un département</option>
                <?php
                    // Call up departments and display them in dropdown list
                    $req = "SELECT DepartementId, RegionId, NomDepartement FROM departements ORDER BY NomDepartement";
                    $rep = mysqli_query($db, $req);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rep)) {
                        echo "<option value=".$row['DepartementId']." class=".$row['RegionId'].">".$row['NomDepartement']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
 
            <!-- Zip Code Textbox -->
            <input type="text" name="codepostal" id="codepostal" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="5">
            
                <!-- Call up countries to display them in dropdown list -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#codepostal").blur(function(){
                            var cp = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'post',
                                data: {codePostal:cp},
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success:function(response){
                                    var len = response.length;
                                    $("#commune").empty();
                                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++ ){
                                        var id = response[i]['id'];
                                        var name = response[i]['name'];
                                        $("#commune").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            
                <?php 
                    // Handle AJAX request (start)              
                    $codepostal = 0;
                    if( isset($_POST['codePostal']) ){
                        $codepostal = $_POST['codePostal'];
                    }
                    $comm_arr = array();
                    if($codepostal > 0){
                        
                        // Query Db and store the Countries corresponding to Zip Code in an aray
                        $req = "    SELECT communes.CommuneId cid, NomCommune FROM communes
                                    LEFT JOIN communeCP
                                    ON communeCP.CommuneId = communes.CommuneId
                                    LEFT JOIN codesPostaux
                                    ON codesPostaux.CodePostalId = communeCP.CodePostalId
                                    WHERE codesPostaux.CodePostal = '$codepostal' ORDER BY NomCommune";
                        $rep = mysqli_query($db, $req);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rep)) {
                            $commId = $row['cid'];
                            $commune = $row['NomCommune'];      
                            $comm_arr = array("id" => $commId, "name" => $commune);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // encoding array to json format
                    echo json_encode($comm_arr);
                ?>
            <!-- Countries dropdown list -->
            <select name="commune" id="commune">
                <option value="0">Sélectionner une commune</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I fund the solution. Now, I'm trying to add features. I would display in the old or new regions in the drop down list, base on the radio buttons selections.
The feature works. But, I could not figure out how to display the departments. I need 2 regions variables, one for the new regions and another if select old regions. But they're not send to PHP. Here is my code:

```
    var gReg = {};
var reg = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='choix']").click(function(){
        
        // Populate Dropdownlist with new region names
        if ($(this).val() === '1') {
            $('#region').find('option').not(':first').remove();
            
            // AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'communes.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {request: 1}, 
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $("#region").click(function(){
                        var len = response.length;
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            var grandeRegionId = response[i]['grandeRegionId'];
                            var nomGrandeRegion = response[i]['nomGrandeRegion'];
                            function gReg() {
                                regype.gdeRegId = grandeRegionId;
                            } 
                            $("#region").append("<option value='"+grandeRegionId+"'>"+nomGrandeRegion+"</option>");
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        // Populate Dropdownlist with old region names
        } else if ($(this).val() === '2') {
        
        // AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'communes.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {request: 2},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $("#region").click(function(){
                        var len = response.length;
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            var regionId = response[i]['regionId'];
                            var nomRegion = response[i]['nomRegion'];
                            function reg() {
                                regype.regId = regionId;
                            }
                            $("#region").append("<option value='"+regionId+"'>"+nomRegion+"</option>");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        // End condition

        
        // Populate dropdown list with departments                                  
        $('#region').blur(function(){
            function regionType() {
                regype.gdeRegId = grandeRegionId;
                
                // AJAX request
                // Populate it with departments based on grandeRegionId (New Regions)
                if (grandeRegionId > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'communes.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {request: 3, grandeRegionId: gdRegId},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            $("#departement").click(function(){ 
                                var len = response.length;
                                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                                    var departementId = response[i]['departementId'];
                                    var nomDepartement = response[i]['nomDepartement'];
                                    $("#departement").append("<option value='"+departementId+"'>"+nomDepartement+"</option>");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    
                // Populate it with departments based on regionId (Old Regions)
                } else if (regionId > 0) {
                    var regId = $(this).val();
                    function regionType() {
                        regype.regId = regionId;
                        // AJAX request
                        if (regionId > 0) {
                            $.ajax({
                            url: 'communes.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {request: 3, regionId: regId},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(response){
                                $("#departement").click(function(){ 
                                    var len = response.length;
                                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                                        var departementId = response[i]['departementId'];
                                        var nomDepartement = response[i]['nomDepartement'];
                                        $("#departement").append("<option value='"+departementId+"'>"+nomDepartement+"</option>");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```